# Why pod library still can be used after i delete it from Podfile?

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

I added this into my Podfile:

```
pod 'RDVTabBarController'
```

Then I ran `pod install`. Then I added `import RDVTabBarController` on my view controller and all works well.

I removed  `pod 'RDVTabBarController` from the Podfile, then ran `pod install` again. Why can I still use it on my `ViewController`? Is `RDVTabBarController` still installed as a reference on my computer?

Answer (score 0):

If you run `pod update` it should remove it from your project. I would also run a `Clean` from within Xcode to ensure that all build stages are started over from scratch.

Comment: I don't think it will help, how about i don't want to update other libraries? In the way my question mentions the library has been removed from the pods folder.